# In Vue.js how to make radios reuseable?

Tags: vue.js

Just started learning vue.js, in the following case, How to fix the problem that radio values got repeated in the v-for div?

https://jsfiddle.net/794xkk97/3/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="questOne">
    <p>{{question}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in selections">
            <input type="radio" v-model="checked" :value="item.val">{{ item.txt }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{ checked }}</p>
</div>
<div id="questFive">
    <div v-for="item in trunk">
        {{ item.question }}
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in selections">
                <input type="radio" v-model="checked" :value="item.val">{{ item.txt }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{ checked }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you, the problem is your v-model for all that radio button bind to the same item, which would cause the duplication results. Please take a look at the link https://jsfiddle.net/794xkk97/4/ . (The other solution is making your own vue-radio button)

Adjusted the trunk item:

```
 trunk: [{
            question: 'sub question1',
            id: 'group1'
        }, {
            question: 'sub question2',
            id: 'group2'
        }, {
            question: 'sub question3',
            id: 'group3'
        }],
```

Adjusted the checked data item:

```
checked: {
            group1: '',
            group2: '',
            group3: ''
        },
```

And the v-loop:

```
<div v-for="itemT in trunk">
        {{ itemT.question }}
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in selections">
                <input type="radio" v-model="checked[itemT.id]" :value="item.val">{{ item.txt }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{ checked[itemT.id] }}</p>
    </div>
```